# Strange behavior of condition_variable in C++

Tags: c++, synchronization

I have experimented to modify C++ example code of condition_variable so that the variable is notified before waiting is initiated. I end up with the code, where I do not notify at all but all the threads are awake.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
 
std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex cv_m; // This mutex is used for three purposes:
                 // 1) to synchronize accesses to i
                 // 2) to synchronize accesses to std::cerr
                 // 3) for the condition variable cv
int i = 0;
 
void waits(int id)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
    for (int t=10; t!=0; t--)
    {
        std::cerr << id << " waiting " << t <<" seconds... \n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
    // cv.wait(lk);
    cv.wait(lk, []{return i == 1;});
    for (int t=10; t!=0; t--)
    {
        std::cerr << id << " finish waiting " << t <<" seconds... \n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}
 
void signals()
{
//    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
        std::cerr << "Notifying...\n";
    }
//    cv.notify_all();
 
//    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
 
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
        i = 1;
        std::cerr << "Notifying again...\n";
    }
//    cv.notify_one();
}
 
int main()
{
    std::thread t1(waits, 0), t2(waits, 1), t3(waits, 2), t4(signals);
    t1.join(); 
    t2.join(); 
    t3.join();
    t4.join();
}
```

Interestingly without predicate calling just `cv.wait(lk);` in `waits` causes infinite waiting. So it seems when the predicate is satisfied, no waiting occurs? See https://onlinegdb.com/Sr4iaHu5T So is there some magic going on or this is expected? The consequence is that `cv.wait(lk, []{return true;});` causes no waiting and is not equivalent to `cv.wait(lk);`.

Is this something I can rely on? I mean I could call `cond_var.wait(lock, []() { return !packet_queue.empty(); });` and know that if the queue isn't empty it won't wait even without notification.

Comment: Side note: Be aware of [spurious wakeup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup)s - they are a real thing and *do* happen on some platform / tool-chain combinations.

Comment: Also actual waiting is done after condition is checked and not met.

Comment: If you remove/reduce sleep in `waits` and make sleep longer in `signal` then app freezes as expected, since `cv.wait(lk, []{return i == 1;});` will be reached before `i` is changed to meet condition.

Comment: See also [std::condition_variable::wait with predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33692574)